# Is there a tactical purpose for the hole in Power Girl's costume?

Tags: dc

The DC superhero Power Girl wears a white costume with a red cape. Her costume has a cleavage-displaying cutout. Is there an in-universe, tactical explanation for this? Out of universe, it just seems like basic comic book sexism, but has any comic book writer given an in-universe explanation for the cutout?

[image: Cleavage Girl]

[image: Power Girl]

Comment: Distract male opponents?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CleavageWindow  Note the page image.

Comment: @JonCuster In The Boys it's all market research .. to entice fans to buy merchandise and prop up profits.

Comment: @PeterM - clearly, yes, but it may also have some tactical use...

Comment: @JonCuster Hmmm .. I suppose selling merchandise is more *strategic* than tactical.   But at least they do have an in-universe rational.

Comment: https://static0.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Power-Girl-Comic-Suit-Chest-Window-Explained.jpg?q=50&fit=crop&w=740&h=821&dpr=1.5

Comment: https://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/505/540/282.jpg

Comment: https://townsquare.media/site/622/files/2009/11/justno-456.jpg

Comment: https://www.oglaf.com/oriel/ (warning, Oglaf is generally NSFW although this one is fine)

Comment: All I see is pictures. What is the question?

Comment: https://www.fracturemechanics.org/hole.html.  stress mechanics in the costume

Comment: How would deciding to write a fictional character in a way that she does not mind/appreciate showing skin be sexist?

Comment: Increases airflow and delays overheating and fatigue in strenuous fights.

Comment: Kate BEatone has [provided an analysis of a similar problem in a Marvel character](http://www.harkavagrant.com/index.php?id=398).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently there have been a few different justifications for the outfit over the years. A particularly notable explanation, from *JSA: Classified #2* (2005), is that the costume was *intended* to have a symbol on the chest, like Superman's, but she never came up with anything and just left it empty.

[image: sad power girl explains her cleavage window]

> People always ask me *why* I have this *hole* right here. They think I'm showing off ... or just being *lewd*. But the first time I made this costume, I wanted to have a *symbol* like you.
>
> I just... I couldn't *think* of anything. I thought, eventually, I'd figure it out - and *close* the hole.
>
> But I *haven't*.

This is not really a tactical reason for having a cleavage window, but it is at least an in-universe explanation. Apparently she was suffering from something of an identity crisis during this period, so she found her lack of symbolism particularly poignant.

Not being a reader of the comics, I'm only aware of this particular explanation for the costume because the scene of Power Girl having a tearful monologue that emotionally "justifies" her outfit was widely mocked on the internet. I'd be very surprised if no comic has ever canonicalised the simple joke that it's there to distract the kind of opponents who are easily distracted by breasts on display - I have seen panels where that property is remarked upon in-universe, though not given as the actual reasoning for the design.

Comment: Absence of logo idea is plain cloth, not hole. She lied on the face.

Comment: This page has an example of the "it throws opponents off balance" explanation: https://comicsalliance.com/power-girl-lectures-women-for-complaining-about-her-costume/

Comment: This comic strip sounds and looks totally wrong ...

Answer (score 6):

The story that I heard was that her cleavage was due to the artist Wally Wood. It seems that Wally was bored, so he kept increasing her breast size each issue until somebody complained. I think he found another project before anybody complained, but they kept the look.

The "breast window" just made the problem more obvious.

Comment: Where did you hear this story?

Comment: I forget where I first heard it, but the youtuber Casually Comics repeated it in one of her episodes. It's been knocking about the comics community for quite some time, however.

Comment: It's on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Girl#Physical_appearance_and_costumes Wikipedia's source is listed as: Karyn Pinter. "Jimmy Palmiotti: Time Bomb and Power Girl - the Breast of Friends? - Comics Bulletin"

Comment: @user14111 Yes, Wally Wood. Sorry, too little sleep recently.

Comment: Not to mention how the breasts seem to have migrated upwards until they're level with her shoulders...